# Rails rake 'Don't know how to build task '

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to run my rake task in the terminal with multiple arguments, however I keep getting an error:

```
rake populate:user['a' 'a'] 
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'populate:user[a'
```

My rake file:

```
namespace :populate do
  desc 'Populate data into our database'

  task :user, [:username, :password] => :environment do |t, args|
    // do stuff, also doesn't work when I delete everything inside here
  end
end
```

I have also tried

```
rake populate:user[a, a]
```

It does run without any parameters:

```
rake populate:user
```

Comment: Can you try using rake 'populate:user[a,a]'

Comment: That seemed to work, thank you. Any idea why the other ways didn't work?

Comment: I will post it as a answer please accept

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try using

`rake 'populate:user[a,a]'`

Also you can ref https://cobwwweb.com/4-ways-to-pass-arguments-to-a-rake-task

Answer (score 2):

#### Just remove the space(s) between the arguments.

Use the following:

```
rake populate:user[a,a]
```

There shouldn't be any need to add quotes around the entire rake task or around each argument (I don't think).